# Failed to get program UUIDs from the cache for site in Openedx Applications

Tags: python, openedx, edx, juniper

This is mainly openedx dashboard course page not coming related program.

> Failed to get program UUIDs from the cache for site

Answer (score 0):

In edxapp user create env (source ../edxapp_env) and then run this command

> python manage.py lms --settings production/devstack cache_programs